# Downloading chart as image

Tags: javascript, browser, charts, download

I've a JavaScript chart. I want to make it downloadable in various formats eg.`png,jpg,jpeg,pdf`  etc.
How to do it in client side? Because I don't want to load my server's processing capacity.

Thank you

Comment: Be more specific! What dose you chart look like? canvas, svg, html? Show us some code... It's like saying "I got one bucket of color, what color should I mix it with to make it purple?"

Comment: if using google charts, see `getImageURI`

Comment: I'm using chartjs

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make a screenshot of the div or HTML tag you are using to display the chart and make the user download it.

Using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "Image.png"); 
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Once you press the button with the id btnSave it converts the widget div to a canvas element and then uses the saveAs() FileSaver interface (via FileSaver.js in browsers that don't support it natively) to save the div as an image named "Image.png".

FileSaver.js might not work well on all browsers. Some might not start automatically the download, others might show the image in an other tab. But still i think it is a good solution.

If the chart is already a canvas then you don't need to convert it to canvas and ignore the html2canvas part.